# How to send activity to Firebase Message value or call activity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to send activity to Firebase Message value or call activity?

[FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) extends `Service` class , use class Context in which extending FirebaseMessagingService service class as first parameter to Intent constructor.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClassName.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: already, debug thtat new Intent (this,MainActivity.class)). but Not call MainActivity and not get "message" value. checked Log message "null".              thanks "K"

Comment: @hanbit: onMessageReceived method is executing or not?

Comment: yes I'm executed . when get the "message" from php("json") I wanna send  value to activity from firebase message. Add when get the message from firebase , i hope call " popup.class"